# In c#.net string contain few paragraph like <p></p> but I want first paragraph substring how i can get it

Tags: c#

```
//  Extract News List for SectionID Received;
String sSQL = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(NW_MakerDate, '%d %M %Y') as                     MakerDate";
sSQL = sSQL + " FROM bhavnagari.news_master";
sSQL = sSQL + " WHERE NW_Section = '" + lblSectionID.Text.ToString() +                  "'";
sSQL = sSQL + " ORDER BY Nw_SerialNo DESC";

DataSet DS1 = new DataSet();
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(sSQL,conn);
da.Fill(DS1);

if (DS1.Tables["table"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    str1 = DS1.Tables["table"].Rows[0]["Nw_Detail"].ToString();

    str3 = str1.Replace("<p>", "");
    str3 = str3.Replace("</p>", " ");

    String[] str3 = str3.Split(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        News_DetailIntro = str3[i];

    }

}
```

In the code above, there is one string containing paragraphs. I want to fetch only the first paragraph from this string. How can I do that?

Comment: Please be careful about formatting..

Answer (score 3):

Just try with this function ,

```
private string GetFirstParagraph(string yourHtmltext)
    {
        Match m = Regex.Match(yourHtmltext, @"<p>\s*(.+?)\s*</p>");
        if (m.Success)
        {
            return m.Groups[1].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return yourHtmltext;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
     String str1 = "/*your data*/";
     int index1=str1.IndexOf("<p>");
     int index2=str1.IndexOf("</p>");

     if(index1!=-1 && index2!=-1)
     String finalStr=str1.Substring(index1+3,index2-3));
```